# Simplifying a trigonometric equation for chart radius

Tags: trigonometry

I am making a neat new charting application, yet I am stumped by this equation:

$$M=\dfrac{R}{\cos\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right)}+(\tan\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right) \cdot R)$$

I need to solve for $R$, but for some reason I am throwing a blank. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: are you stumped by
$$
\frac{R}{a} + bR = R(\frac{1}{a} + b)
$$
?

Comment: What? Let's not play games @Chinny84 , I'm not even sure what that is...

Comment: @WebWanderer Chinny84 is generalizing what you should do. You have the case of $a = \cos(\theta/2)$ and $b = \tan(\theta/2)$.

Comment: It was a serious question, and I get a feeling by your response that your post is not.

Comment: Thanks @graydad , and yes Chinny84 , it is a serious question, no need to be flustered by my response. You should realize that the people asking _questions_ are most likely not as savvy as yourself. Have a little heart, I obviously am not as good at this. It was a pretty simple answer.

Comment: I apologise, I assumed that given your response, and the fact your using relatively complex trig functions, that you may be trolling. I would never knowingly put some one down for not seeing something straight away.. I myself, is constantly blown away but people's skill in mathematics on here. Anyway keep at the maths.

Comment: It's ok @Chinny84 , I guess I did sound a little salty. Sorry about that. Thanks for the help, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: $$\dfrac{R}{\cos\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right)}+(\tan\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right) \cdot R) = R\left(\dfrac{1}{\cos\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right)}+\tan\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: AHHHH! I feel so dumb! I knew something about it looked easy! Thanks!